# ExtJs Adding additional files to build

Tags: extjs, extjs7

How to use 'app.json' to add additional files to the production build when I use the following command

`sencha app build`

For example, I have some static HTML pages updated regularly located in the root directory, so I want those files to be copied to the production directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `build.xml` file located in the project's root directroy. Add the following to the main `<project>` block:

```
<target name="-after-build">
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/myfolder">
        <fileset dir="${app.dir}/myfolder" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${build.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${app.dir}">
            <include name="favicon.ico"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

The first example copies an entire folder, the second copies a file from the project root folder to the build folder.